# Ajax multiple data point post to MVC core Error 400

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am attempting to AJAX JQuery post some form data to my MVC controller but I'm getting an error of 400. I am attempting to post by doing:

```js
 var count = $('#MediaList').children().length;        
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {           
            $.post('/Submit/MediaAdd',
                { model: $('.AddMedia:nth-child(' + i + ')').find('form').serialize(), count: count }
            );
        }
```

The information is supposed to go into this method:

```cs
 [Route("/Submit/MediaAdd")]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] //Add media form handler
 public IActionResult MediaAdd(Media model, int count)
 {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       //do stuff to model and count
    }
 }
```

Finally, here is a shortened version of my form:

```html
<form name="mediaAdd" method="post">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="container">        
        <div class="form-row">
            <label asp-for="Medias.Blurb" class="control-label">Blurb
                 <span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span> 
                 <span class="text-muted ml-1">Explain what is in the media</span>
            </label>
            <input asp-for="Medias.Blurb" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Medias.Blurb" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row col-5">
            <div class="form-group MediaLink">
                 <label for="FileLink">Link the Media</label>
                 <input asp-for="Medias.SourceFile" type="url" class="form-control" id="FileLink">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: use [HttpPost] over action in controller

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't change anything. Btw, if I do ``` $.post('/Submit/MediaAdd', $('.AddMedia:nth-child(1)').find('form').serialize());``` I can hit a breakpoint inside of ```MediaAdd``` but model is completely empty/ full of nulls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took three things to fix it fully. First remove the `Medias.` from the front of the asp-for. Secondly, the Controller Method wants an input in the form of a JSON array. So I had to convert the serialized output to a JSON array. Lastly, I need to validate the input, meaning that I need to pass the verification token to the method, I stole the code for that from user Yiyi You. This can be done by the following code:

```js
function SubmitMedia () {
        var count = $('#MediaList').children().length;
        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();     
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var data = $('.AddMedia:nth-child(1)').find('form').serialize().split("&");
        console.log(data);
        var obj = {};
        for (var key in data) {
            console.log(data[key]);
            obj[data[key].split("=")[0]] = data[key].split("=")[1];
        }
        console.log(obj);
            $.post('/Submit/MediaAdd',
                { __RequestVerificationToken: token, model: obj, count: count },
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is caused by `{ model: $('.AddMedia:nth-child(' + i + ')').find('form').serialize(), count: count }`.Here is a demo worked:

Media.cs:

```
public class Media
    {
        public string Blurb { get; set; }
        public string SourceFile { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
 [Route("/Submit/MediaAdd")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] //Add media form handler
        public IActionResult MediaAdd(Media model, int count)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Ok();
            }
            return Ok();
        }
```

View:

```
@model Media
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Media";
}

<h1>Media</h1>
<form name="mediaAdd" method="post" id="dataForm">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-row">
            <label asp-for="Blurb" class="control-label">
                Blurb
                <span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span>
                <span class="text-muted ml-1">Explain what is in the media</span>
            </label>
            <input asp-for="Blurb" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Blurb" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row col-5">
            <div class="form-group MediaLink">
                <label for="FileLink">Link the Media</label>
                <input asp-for="SourceFile" type="url" class="form-control" id="FileLink">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="sendData()">send</button>
</form>
@section scripts{ 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendData() {
        var count = 1;
        var formdata = {};
        formdata.Blurb = $('input[name="Blurb"]').val();
        formdata.SourceFile = $('input[name="SourceFile"]').val();
        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
        $.post('/Submit/MediaAdd',
            { __RequestVerificationToken: token, model: formdata, count: count }
            );
    }
</script>
}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, especially the part where you verified the token. However, if you look at my answer, I think it can be done in a simpler way